# How to insert into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

how should I insert some data into JSON?

I need to create a JSON file through a script. The JSON file should look like this:

```
{
    "index": {
        "colors": [
            {
                "title": "great color",
                "name": "nice color"
            },
            {
                "title": "worst color",
                "name": "bad color"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

in my javascript file i amable to push to the colors array:

```
var index = {index: {}};
var posts = {colors: []};
var single = {title: "great color", name: "nice color"};

posts.colors.push(single);
```

however, how do i insert it into the index object? i am writing to a JSON file currently like this:

```
fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2));
```

but this writes only the colors array, and the resulting JSON file is like this:

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
            "title": "great color",
            "name": "nice color"
        },
        {
            "title": "worst color",
            "name": "bad color"
        }
    ]
}
```

how can i create the JSON structure that i need?

Comment: Please post your code **here**. Do you really require us to open three different pages to understand what you're talking about?!

Comment: sorry, i didnt realize i could just paste it all in here!
Tyr has answered me well, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the color array into the index object:

```
var obj = {}; // basic object

obj['index'] = {}; // The index child object
obj.index['colors'] = new Array(); // the color array below index

var single = {title: "great color", name: "nice color"};
obj.index.colors.push(single);
```

Comment: Since I can't write my own answer because the question is on hold, I'll put it in a comment here. This would be much more concise: http://jsfiddle.net/k8jqpkrb/

Answer (score 0):

Now that I can write my own answer, try this instead:

```
var obj = {
        index: {
            colors: []
        }
    }, // basic object
    single = {
        title: "great color",
        name: "nice color"
    };

obj.index.colors.push(single);

// ...

fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

I'm not sure why you need to make the objects separately but I just assumed you were adding the indeces for the colors somewhere else so I left that separate. It's just less verbose this way.